Can a prepositional phrase be the subject of a sentence?
Before lunch is the best time to take a nap.
Is the phrase before lunch the subject in this sentence? Or is the true subject the word time? Thank you very much.

Yes, your prepositional phrase before lunch is the subject.

If "before lunch" is the subject, wouldn't that mean "best time" is an adverbial phrase? And what happens when we reverse the sentence: "The best time to take a nap is before lunch." Does the phrase "before lunch" also become an adverbial phrase? Thank you very much.

@cookie234 In neither case is "before lunch" an adverbial phrase. If you have a new question, post it separately, not in the comments.

Before lunch = best time. SVC. cf. Under the bed is dusty.

Yes, the PP "before lunch" is the subject in your example. "The best time to take a nap" is a noun phrase functioning as predicative complement of "is". We know that the PP is the subject because it is the subject in the tag question "isn't it?

"Before lunch" is a shortened form of "the time before lunch", which is a noun phrase. We can see this as the sentence continues with "the best time", which, itself can be replaced with "the better time." Thus "time" serves as the base for the superlative/comparative.
